# AngularJS, Factory, Provider or Services

Tags: angularjs, variables, service, provider

I'm trying to save a variable in my application containing the username, I have a login page (**a directive**) where I get the username. I tried:

**Provider**: it save my variable but I can only change before the app load and I need to change the variable after inside a controller.

```
.provider('username',function(){

    var username = 'Default';

    return {
        setName: function(value) { 
            username = value; 
        },
        $get: function() { 
            return { 
                 name: username 
            } 
        }
    }
```

**Services:** it works ok, but if I refresh the page I lose the variable.

```
.service('username', function () {

    var username;
    this.setName = function (value) {
        username = value;
    }
    this.name = function () {
        return username;
    }
})
```

Can some tell me what is the best approach for that? I'm struggling for hours to come up with something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually **use a factory**, seems perfect, but like you said you lose all your data when refreshing your page.

This behavious is not related to Angular of Factory object, but to **Javascript and your browser**. You need to save this value in a storage object (cookies, sessionStorage, localStorage, here is a link if you never used them : [Difference between Session Storage, Local Storage and Cookies in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172976/difference-between-session-storage-local-storage-and-cookies-in-angularjs)).

In you case, in `this.setName` you store it in let's say `sessionStorage`, and when initializing your factory you just check if this value exist.

```
.service('username', function ($window) {
    var username = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    this.setName = function (value) {
        username = value;
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('user', value);
    }
    this.name = function () {
        return username;
    }
})
```

*(This code might not be perfect, like if the value does not exist might be good to have a dedicated scenario, but give you a good idea about how to use it in your case)*

Comment: Alright, that makes a lot of sense.. thanks @sebastienbarbier very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a factory service that uses your browser's local storage/session storage to store session data

try going over these questions

[Maintaining Session through Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js)

[AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)